# Surge protection

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, protection, surge-suppression

I have an outdoor meter socket with a 150 amp panel for the heat pump and just inside the house I have a 200 amp whole house service.  Where is the best place to install this surge protector.  I would like to put in the outside box under the meter socket.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the meter/meter main/etc.?

Comment: Define "best". What are you trying to protect?

Answer (score 2):

From the Square D documentation on the surge protector I just installed for my panel:

> Note: The SPD requires two adjacent mounting spaces
> and should be installed as close to the main circuit
> breaker, or main lugs as possible.

Extrapolating that, you will want to place the surge protection as close to the main feed as possible, which for you is your meter-main panel.  If that panel has the space, you should locate it there.